# How to write mysql subselect properly with conditions and limiting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three Tables:

Posts:
id, title, authorId, text

authors:
id, name, country

Comments:
id, authorId, text, postId

I want to run a mysql command which selects the first 5 posts which were written by authors, whose country is 'Ireland'. In the same call, I want to retrieve all the comments for those five posts, and also the author info.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT posts.id as 'posts.id', posts.title as 'posts.title'  (etc. etc. list all fields in three table)
FROM 
(SELECT *  FROM posts, authors WHERE authors.country = 'ireland' AND authors.id = posts.authorId LIMIT 0, 5 ) as posts 
LEFT JOIN 
comments ON comments.postId = posts.id, 
authors 
WHERE
authors.id = posts.authorId
```

I had to include every field with an alias ^  because there was a duplicate for id, and more fields in future may become duplicates as I'm looking for a generic solution.

My two questions are:

1) I am getting a duplicate field entry from within my subselect for id, so do I have to list out all my fields as aliases again within the subselect or is there only one field I need for a subselect

2) Is there a way to auto-alias my call? At the moment I've just aliased every field in the main select but can it do this for me so there are no duplicates?

Sorry if this isn't very clear it's a bit of a messy problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an unnecessary join back to the `author` table in your query.  You get all the fields you want in the `posts` subquery.  I would rename this to something other than an existing table, perhaps `pa` to indicate posts and authors.

You say you want the first 5 posts, but have no order clause.  A better form of the query is:

```
SELECT pa.id as 'posts.id', pa.title as 'posts.title'  (etc. etc. list all fields in three table)
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM posts join
           authors
           on authors.id = posts.authorId
      WHERE authors.country = 'ireland'
      order by post.date
      LIMIT 0, 5
     ) pa LEFT JOIN 
     comments c
     ON c.postId = pa.id
```

Note that this returns the first five posts and their authors (as specified in the question).  But one author may be responsible for all five posts.

In MySQL, you can use `*` and it will get rid of duplicate aliases in the `from` clause.  I think this is dangerous.  It is better to list all the columns you want.

Comment: Thanks! Point about the second unnecessary join taken, and forgot the order date :p Does SELECT * in the sub-select not result in' Mysql error: Duplicate column name 'id' ' seeing as both authors and posts have an id?

Comment: Also, id I only selected posts.id in my subselect, would that mean I only have access to the post's id in the main statement?

Comment: @user1020317 . . . Yes.  Then you have to join back in the `authors` table to get those fields.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. You can select as many (or as few) columns as you need from a sub-query
2. You do not need to join the `authors` table again since you already selected all fields in the sub-query (and so get rid of duplicate columns names).

A few additional remarks...

**... about the `JOIN` syntax**

Prefer the form

```
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.fk = t2.pk)
```

to the obsolete, obscure

```
FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.fk = t2.pk
```

**... about the use of a `LIMIT` clause without an `ORDER BY` clause**

The order in which rows are returned by a `SELECT` statement without an `ORDER BY` clause is undefined. Therefore, a `LIMIT n` clause without an `ORDER BY` clause could return any *n* rows in theory.

Your final query should look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM posts
    JOIN authors ON (authors.id = posts.authorId )
    WHERE authors.country = 'ireland'
    ORDER BY posts.id DESC -- assuming this column is monotonically increasing
    LIMIT 5
) AS last_posts 
LEFT JOIN comments ON ( comments.postId = last_posts .id )
```